# Programmatically highlighting DyGraph time series

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I’m putting together an web-app that plots time series of weather data for the current year and the past 10 years on one dygraph. I want the time series for the current year (2015 at this time) to be highlighted relative to the past years, so I’m trying to increase the strokewidth for the current year from a default of 2 to 5.  My problem is that I’m having trouble getting this to work programatically. The daily data for each year  is in native array format, so the time series  are identified by the contents of the array Yr0Labels:

["Date", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"]

Next January 1 the Yr0Labels will programmatically change to:

["Date", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",”2016”]

In the dygraph options parameter  I set default strokeWidth to 2 and the  strokeWidth for 2015 to 5. Because I want the current calendar year data to be highlighted  properly after Jan. 1 ,  I’ve tried  identifying the series to be highlighted by the contents of  yr0Labels[11],

```
    {
     ……
     strokeWidth: 2,
     labels: yr0Labels,
     series: {  yr0Labels[11] : { strokeWidth: 5} }, 
     ……..
   }
```

This produced a syntax error - SyntaxError:       missing : after property id

Suspecting that dygraph didn’t want to see array syntax in the series identifier, I tried to identify the series via a string variable “cyear”,

cyear = yr0Labels[11];

```
    {…strokeWidth: 2, 
         labels: yr0Labels,
         series: {  cyear : { strokeWidth: 5} },
     …….}
```

This  didn’t produce an error, but also didn’t highlight the series.

The only way I’ve been able to make this work is to directly enter the current year value as the series identifier,

```
    {…strokeWidth: 2, 
         labels: yr0Labels,
         series : {  ‘2015’ : { strokeWidth: 5} },
     …….}
```

This worked, but I’d have to edit the dygraph option parameter every Jan. 1 to make data for the current calendar year plot properly.

How I can make this highlighting work programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you're using keys in JavaScript object literals.

This:

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

is the same as:

```
{ 'foo': 'bar' }
```

even if there's a variable in scope called `foo`. To achieve the result you want, you need to do fill out your objects using something like:

```
var foo = 'blah';
var o = {};
o[foo] = 'bar';
```

Comment: The following works, Thanks Again... <br/> var cyear=yr0Labels[11];
       var tempObj = {};
       tempObj[cyear] = { strokeWidth: 5 } ;
       plotOptions['series']= tempObj;